# onOpen is not running to other users except to the owner. How to fix this? Google Script GAS

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, gs-installable-triggers

After refreshing the shared spreadsheet, onOpen is not running to other users who also have access.

But the owner is being able to run the codes and script.

Code.gs

```
function onOpen(e) {
    test();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp, SlidesApp, or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('First item', 'menuItem1')
      .addToUi();
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp, SlidesApp, or FormApp.
        .createMenu('Custom Menu').addItem('Test', 'test').addToUi();
};

function test() {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.
    var result = ui.prompt('Spreadsheet Restriction', 'Enter password:', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
    // Process the user's response.
    var button = result.getSelectedButton();
    var text = result.getResponseText();
    if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
        // User clicked "OK".
    } else if (button == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
        // User clicked X in the title bar.
        ui.alert('Spreadsheet is protected.');
        test();
    }
};
function myFunction() {

}
```

Already shared the access spreadsheet and script to other users but they can't still see it is working.
Appreciate your help guys... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The users of your Sheet/script **must** have edit access on the Sheets document in order for the `onOpen()` trigger to be executed. From the documentation:

   > They do not run if a file is opened in read-only (view or comment) mode.
2. In order to use the `prompt()` method within the `onOpen()` function, you **must** use an installable trigger. Furthermore, the trigger **must** be set up by the user who is going to use it. The same also applies to other functions of the [UI class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui) such as [`showModalDialog()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showModalDialog(Object,String)).

This strict rules are most likely enforced in order to protect the end user of potential scams. If you are interested in protecting your Sheets document with password, I suggest you check out other solutions such as [this one](http://www.skipser.com/p/2/p/password-protect-google-drive-document.html),

#### Reference

- [Simple Triggers restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions)
- [Installable Triggers restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions)