# Creating a prompt that opens upon refreshing a Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Creating a spreadsheet that will upon either being opened or refreshed should pop up a prompt asking me for the day, store that value in a particular cell and then proceed to ask me a series of other questions.

This is what I have so far:

```
function onOpen()
{
 // Prompt for the value
 const day =  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Please enter the day.").getResponseText();
 //Get all pages in spreadsheet and iterate through
 const sheets =   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
 for(var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++ )
 {
  //Set the value in the cell B3 of the page
  sheets[i].getRange("B2").setValue( day );
 }
 if (day.toLowerCase() === 'monday') {
   function martialArts() {
     const mma = ui.alert("Did you go to MMA training today?".ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
     if(mma == ui.Button.YES) {
       sheets.getRange('C2').setValue(mma)
     }
    }
 }  
}
```

When I run the script I only get a prompt asking for the day, if I enter Monday this is stored by the other prompt (the question "Did you go to MMA training today") does not run. Additionally, this script does not run upon opening or refreshing my sheet

Answer (score 0):

Simple triggers have limitations, instead use and installable trigger.

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Related

- [Why does ui.alert work but ui.prompt does not with onOpen()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48853968/1595451)
- [onOpen is not running to other users except to the owner. How to fix this? Google Script GAS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59598298/1595451)

Answer (score 0):

There are some things wrong on your code:

1 - On the `const day` you are using `SpreadsheetApp.getUi()` but on the `const mma` you are using `ui` which is not defined.

2 - You have a function inside an `if` with `function martialArts()`, that should be removed.

3 - On the `for` loop you are selecting the sheet with `sheets[i]` but then on the `if` below you select `sheets` which is all the sheets in the spreadsheet. If you know there is only one sheet or you know which sheets has to be selected you can use `sheets[0]` or set the `if` inside the `for` loop.

With this changes applied your code should look like this:

```js
function onOpen() {
  // Prompt for the value
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const day = ui.prompt("Please enter the day.").getResponseText();
  //Get all pages in spreadsheet and iterate through
  const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  sheets[0].getRange("B2").setValue(day);
  if (day.toLowerCase() === 'monday') {
    const mma = ui.alert('Did you go to MMA training today?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
    if (mma == ui.Button.YES) {
      sheets[0].getRange('C2').setValue(mma)
    }
  }
}
```